# If both pilots are incapacitated, what happens?

Tags: faa-regulations, safety, commercial-operations, pilot-incapacitation

How do the airlines prepare for a situation where for some reason both PIC and SIC are incapacitated for the remainder of the flight?

Comment: [Related question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8986/19)

Comment: What happens? Unfortunately something close to [Helios 522](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helios_Airways_Flight_522)

Comment: It's all explained at the end of this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQbj9uvYL8I

Comment: How do GreyHound and Amtrack prepare for both drivers to be incapacitated?  Oh... they only have one driver to begin with?

Comment: @abelenky Amtrak (nearly all trains, actually) is a really bad example: Train systems are designed to deal with incapacitation using dead-man switches. The train will brake itself to a stop, and the block signaling system will indicate the track is occupied to prevent other trains from crashing into the one that's stopped. It's actually incredibly hard to crash two trains into each other. Implementing equivalent functionality for aircraft is much harder, because planes don't run on tracks…

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis To be fair, in that incident, the person didn't enter the cockpit until almost the exact same time that an engine flamed out from fuel starvation and the person was probably also still suffering, at least somewhat, from hypoxia.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[How does Airbus prepare for a dual engine failure on the A320?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Airways_Flight_1549)

The short answer is this isn't something that's realistically planned for because the chance of a double-failure of the redundant systems in question (the two pilots) is pretty unlikely, and many of the conditions that could lead to it would result in a catastrophic loss of the aircraft anyway.

(The most notable exception to that would be a loss of pressurization at altitude, in which case hopefully at least *one* of the pilots can get their oxygen mask on to make the emergency descent.)

---

The ATC/Airline system as a whole can *theoretically* deal with this sort of a double failure in a few different ways. The most common is finding an off-duty employee of the airline who is riding non-revenue (dead-head, jumpseat, etc.) to fill the role of an incapacitated crew member.
This is of course predicated on whatever incapacitated the flight crew not affecting this other person.

If no qualified personnel are available it may be possible to get an experienced instructor on the radio to "talk the plane down", but that relies on having someone onboard who can (a) get access to the cockpit, and (b) at least figure out how to operate the radios to ask for help.
"Talk-Down Landings" have happened [in small aircraft](http://abcnews.go.com/US/story?id=96248) on several occasions, but [as best I can determine this has never happened in a transport-category aircraft (airliner)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_down_aircraft_landing) outside of [simulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/8997/64) and similar thought experiments.

Comment: In response to the second paragraph, there was Helios 522...

Comment: @raptortech97 I'm sure that's not the only case of dual-pilot incapacitation either, but I bet you'd have a hard time naming 5 without really digging. It's an *incredibly* rare event, and solutions are pretty hard to make workable (anything that would incapacitate a 2-person crew would likely incapacitate a 3-person crew, so adding more people doesn't help, and solutions get more difficult to implement from there).

Comment: @voretaq7, an ability to remote-control the plane from the ground, like a drone, would do it.

Comment: @AE Remote control of airliners will happen as soon as someone can implement it securely (it needs to be literally *unhackable* or someone will crash a plane into a building with it), reliably (at least as reliable as a second pilot), and cheaply (it has to cost less than a second pilot). In other words, "not any time soon".

Comment: @voretaq7, I was thinking about those things - or security and reliability at least - when I made my comment, and what I thought was: surely war-drones must be secure (or as secure as they can be) and reliable? Because otherwise the enemy would take control of them. Which (as far as we know) has never happened.

Comment: @AE [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran–U.S._RQ-170_incident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran–U.S._RQ-170_incident)

Comment: @voretaq7 - oh! - interesting!

Comment: @AE - Any remote electronic device is "hackable" once you get one hand on the software and/or hardware scheme. High level of secured system is likely to be non standard, advanced, proprietary, and sometimes classified technology. Put that in a common place (airplane) and you'll be hacked 10000 times faster. I don't claim the RQ170 incident is true story (reverse engineering of this level is likely unbelievable) Anyway, remotely taking control in mid flight is already an hack to begin with. To secure that, you'll have to confirm the control delegate from the airplane itself, but wait..... :/

Comment: I suppose one solution would be to implement remote control with a physical disconnect accessible to the pilots. Also, it would need to give the pilots an **extremely** noticeable warning upon its activation and should be automatically disabled during critical flight phases. It should also probably give the pilots a warning for, say, 60 seconds before going active, so that they have a chance to stop it before control is gained in the case of a hack.

Comment: Well this goes against what I have been told on here, that it would be impossible for an untrained person to be talked down to landing an A320 (Something I was hoping to train in)

Answer (score 2):

In the *highly* unlikely event of this, a person who knows something about planes would get instructions from ATC of how to fly. A few years back there was a helios A320 which had a pressurisation issue. Everyone was un conscious and a member of the cabin crew attempted to land the plane. Thou, it was un successful. To sum up, ATC Would instruct someone how to fly and then auto land the plane, and this would most likely never happen.