Has any flight crew ever had to ask "Does anyone on board know how to fly a plane?"
Having just watched the classic movie 'Airplane' I'm curious if any crew of a large(ish) passenger aircraft has ever had to make a P.A. announcement asking for someone to fly a plane, and if so, what was the passengers reaction?
I'm not asking if any non-pilots have ever landed a plane, I'm curious about if there's ever been a situation where pilot and co-pilot have both been incapacitated and crew have had to identify an off-duty pilot amongst the passengers.

Related:https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11677/36893

This could happen if one of the pilots is incapacitated. While one pilot should always be able to safely fly and land an airliner, having a second person to handle the radio and other things can really help with workload, even if that second person is not qualified to fly that particular type of airplane.

Very related: Can a passenger realistically replace suddenly incapacitated pilots?

Of course you have the easy cases of crews with more than 2 pilots (very long flights have relief pilots), with a check captain or supervising check captain (see QF32), pilots deadheading or just flying gratuitously. Depending on the emergency, other qualified pilots on board may notice and offer their help spontaneously.

A PA announcement of that type would simply generate a panic reaction, which is exactly the opposite of what you want in that moment. Instead, in such cases (with both pilot and copilot incapitated) a crew member will normally take over. Off the top of my head I remember the Helios Airways Flight 522:
"At 11:05, two F-16 fighter aircraft from the Hellenic Air Force 111th Combat Wing were scrambled from Nea Anchialos Air Base to establish visual contact. They intercepted the passenger jet at 11:24, and observed that the first officer was slumped motionless at the controls, and the captain's seat was empty. They also reported that oxygen masks were dangling in the passenger cabin. At 11:49, flight attendant Andreas Prodromou entered the cockpit and sat down in the captain's seat, having remained conscious by using a portable oxygen supply. Prodromou held a UK Commercial Pilot Licence but was not qualified to fly the Boeing 737. Prodromou waved at the F-16s very briefly, but almost as soon as he entered the cockpit, the left engine flamed out due to fuel exhaustion and the plane left the holding pattern and started to descend. Crash investigators concluded that Prodromou's experience was insufficient for him to be able to gain control of the aircraft under the circumstances. However, Prodromou succeeded in banking the plane away from Athens and towards a rural area as the engines flamed out, with his actions meaning that there were no ground casualties." (emphasis mine).

I'm not aware of any examples, and it shouldn't really be needed.
The crew should be aware of any company pilots on board, even off duty and out of uniform, and those are the first choice since they'll already know the company procedures.  Example: Air Transat 186.
The second choice would be any other airline, charter or military pilots on board, whom the cabin crew could discreetly identify if they're in uniform.  Example: Southwest 6013.
I've discussed the scenario with some airline pilot friends, and their unanimous opinion is that it'd be safer to continue the flight alone than to invite an unknown pilot, who probably lacks professional CRM training and may be more of a hindrance than a help, into the flight deck.
If both pilots are incapacitated, it's probably a pressurization issue that would incapacitate all the passengers as well, so there is no help to be had anyway or anyone conscious to ask for it.  Example: Helios 522.
