# Could a single engine pilot land a passenger jet? (from Airplane)

Tags: landing

I'm assuming that almost everyone on this website has seen the movie Airplane at least a few times...

Last time I was watching it I was wondering how plausible the actual act of having a single engine prop pilot, with a lot of training (maybe comparable to a modern day aerobatic pilot), land a quad engine passenger jet?

[image]

Comment: A passenger jet has several landing aids, talking to ATC who will get a instructor on the phone and will talk him down through the systems.

Comment: More likely than someone with no experience at all. Remember, the concept of landing a plane is the same for all planes. The technical systems are different maybe, but the general concept is the same.

Comment: We already have this question http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8986/can-a-passenger-realistically-replace-suddenly-incapacitated-pilots

Comment: @SentryRaven "Remember, the concept of landing a plane is the same for all planes." That's not really true. The procedures are actually quite different.

Comment: Not a dupe -- this is the case of say a PPL with an IR and several hundred to a couple thousand hours TT having to take over, vs. someone with no aeronautical experience whatsoever.  (Or, @voretaq7's flying commercial and both the flight crew conk, now what?)

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject the question may be different, but the answer's the same.

Comment: @raptortech97 -- I'd say the answer's not quite the same, but that's just me -- hopefully we'll get some more informed opinions on this over here soon!

Comment: @reirab Yes, the procedures are a lot different. But the concept is everytime the same: descent, stable approach, flare, touchdown, stop. Whoever learned that flying SEP, will have it in mind with every other airframe.

Comment: @SentryRaven The names and basic goals of the phases are the same, but that's about where the similarity ends. I fly SEP, but if I find myself at the controls of an airliner, my most useful knowledge as a pilot will probably be knowing how to declare an emergency and call ATC on the radio asking that they get me a pilot for that type on the radio ASAP to explain how to set up an autoland.

Comment: An experienced single engine pilot is with experience "comparable to a modern day aerobatic pilot" is  NOT the "passenger, without any previous flight experience" as written in the "duplicate". Here more maybe a question "how difficult is for a good pilot to fly unknown type of the aircraft"

Answer (score 9):

I can relate to you the true story of my uncle who successfully landed a large WWII aircraft with no flight training.

He was the flight surgeon on board a large aircraft that got heavily shot up.  Hostile fire killed or severely injured every crew member.

He moved the pilot out of his seat, and contacted a control tower.  With the expert help of the control tower operators, he successfully landed the aircraft.

After the war, he had a private practice in his home where he saw patients.  For patients too ill to come to him, he performed house calls.  He continued to perform house calls until a short time before he passed.

I have always thought his life story would form a compelling foundation for an inspiring movie.

Comment: This does not answer the question as the question asks if a person who has had considerable flight experience on small plane can fly a commercial-type plane in an emergency.

Comment: If a person with no flight experience could successfully land a large aircraft with the help of skilled control tower personnel, then it is reasonable to think that someone with considerable small plane flight experience could possibly perform a similar task, given the same type of assistance.  Unless, of course, their experience somehow gets in the way; that's a possibility, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: Especially as the modern aircraft would a) have more aids (such as autopilot/autoland), and b) probably fly better, not being shot full of holes.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard WWII-era aircraft are closer to what private pilots fly than they are to the airliners of today. I could probably land, say, a B-17 if I really needed to, probably without even getting help from ATC. Flying a modern jet that flies around Mach 0.9 is quite another story, though.

Comment: @jamesqf That assumes you actually know how to use said aids (I'm a pilot and I wouldn't know how to use most of the ones on a modern airliner.) As far as the holes are concerned, unless they've, say, managed to knock off part of the wing or control surfaces or knocked out an engine or two, they wouldn't really affect the flight of most WWII-era planes all that much. Several of those had _intentional_ holes in the fuselage already (such as for guns.) They weren't pressurized back then.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes.**

The question will have subjective answers and this is my opinion.  The basics of flying an airplane doesn't change from a single engine airplane to a big airliner.

The concept of lining up on final, flaring into the touchdown attitude and setting it down is exactly the same.  There are some things that are different; for example, retractible landing gear, leading edge slats, spoilers and thrust reversers.

Many of the differences can be overcome by talking with ATC and an instructor / pilot trained to fly that airplane through the radio.  The biggest challenge would be knowing when to flare as you are sitting much higher in an airliner than in a single engine airplane.  This can be overcome with listening to the radar altimeter and flaring as directed by the instructor.

Comment: Reverse as a concept *might* be familiar to a SEP pilot -- I believe the Cessna 206/208/210 have it for instance, although those are generally business/fleet aircraft.  The main thrust of the answer makes sense though -- the basic controls and instruments are standardized enough that a PPL/IR would be able to make *some* sense of what's going on, and the rest can be handled by someone with a type rating on the other end of the radio.

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject Yeah, I'd say getting the "someone with a  type rating on the other end of the radio" is the most important part. Hopefully, they can just talk you through setting up an autoland.

Answer (score 5):

I'd share a personal experience: a few years ago I got the chance to fly a Boeing 737 simulator (the *real* thing, not the PC simulator!) At that time the only real aircraft I've flown was a Cessna 172. I managed to land on [Kai Tak airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kai_Tak_Airport) in the simulator on my very first attempt to land a (simulated) 737. I was so nervous that I totally forgot to call for the landing checklist, and the instructor helped me with the gear and flaps, but I was the sole manipulator of the controls and I landed with no automation whatsoever, not even ILS.

How? There were a few factors that came into play:

- I learnt how planes fly in ground school. Big planes fly just the same way as smaller planes, only with larger wings and more powerful engines.
- I knew how to manipulate the flight controls. It came as a bit of a surprise that the controls feel heavier than I'd expect, but they behaved the same anyway.
- My enthusiasm in aviation meant I have learnt beyond the Cessna 172 from books, online articles and PC simulation experience. I was not able to identify every single switch and knob in the cockpit, but I knew enough to fly the plane in that situation.

---

My answer? If it's a perfectly flyable aircraft (no failures), calm weather, then **Yes, definitely!** Here's what I'd do if it happens in real life:

1. **Aviate, navigate, communicate.** No matter what happens, always remember that. That means the first thing to do after entering the cockpit is not to find the radio buttons and call for help; the first thing is to access all primary flight instruments and make sure we're flying.
2. **Radio for help**. Declare an emergency on the last radio frequency. If no one responds, tune to 121.5 and try again.
3. **Request a long runway with calm weather.** Unless it's something like a A380 or Boeing 747, chances are there would be a runway long enough so you don't have to worry about hitting the touchdown spot.
4. **Setup autoland**, if available. Autoland requires suitable equipment both on the plane and on the ground. If it's not available, given a long enough final (say 20 miles), I think I'd feel comfortable hand flying the aircraft down.
5. **Have the emergency trucks standing by**. In the event I crashed during landing, gear collapsed or whatever, everyone'd be ready to help.

Comment: To step this down a level, I did 30 hours on Cessna 152s at 17, having spent a good few hours on basic (Atari ST!) flight simulators and being keen on the physics and engineering of aircraft. With a few exceptions (odd aero effects like stalling in a steep turn and in particular the ground effect on landing) I felt very at home with the basic flight and controls, in retrospect I'd have given myself a 50/50 chance of an landing without damage to the aircraft if thrown into it from scratch. How this scales up is the question though.

Answer (score 4):

My dad, an experienced pilot, was once given the chance to fly a 727 simulator (full motion, the works). He stalled it 40 feet over the runway and the simulator came down hard enough on the stops to hurt his back and scramble the gyros.

That's only one data point, but any rate, the crash would have been survivable, so there's that.

Answer (score 3):

Like anything in aviation, it depends,

There, to date, have been no documented cases of this happening. There have been a few ["talk down landings"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_down_aircraft_landing) in smaller aircraft with low time or inexperienced pilots. Similarly there is at least [one documented case](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOO_oYZF_B0) of an air force [B-1B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockwell_B-1_Lancer) Pilot assisting in [landing an airliner](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/off-duty-pilot-lands-plane-saves-3640802) he had no experience flying but you can argue he had plenty of jet time. People have [tried it in simulators of course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htg0VKt3j_w) but a sim is a sim. Of course things like cross winds and runway length will play into the success rate of an event like this. I will say that the margin of error on these things is small and on a calm day I'm sure it's possible. I would hesitate to give a hard yes to this question since there are far to many factors to take into account but I do feel under the correct circumstances it could be done.

On a small side note, since this question is about Quad Engine planes (747, A380 etc) considering the distances those planes typically fly it's more than likely that there is one if not two relief crews on the plane so the chances of everyone becoming incapacitated and requiring a passenger step up to the plate is slim to none.

Comment: That headline is wrong. The B-1 pilot did _not_ land the airliner. The FO (who was presumably typed on the aircraft in question) landed it while the B-1 pilot presumably did normal PNF tasks. Also, a B-1 pilot will presumably be much more familiar with turbine engines and the level of automation found in a modern airliner than a typical private pilot would be.

Comment: You are correct I realized that after adding the video link, ill alter my answer to reflect that he only assisted.