# Has anyone with no flight training ever landed an aircraft with no assistance?

Tags: emergency, passenger, pilot-incapacitation

There have been successful "talk-down landings" in which someone on the ground has given instructions over radio for a passenger to land an aircraft when the pilot was incapacitated, but has anyone with no flight training ever survivably landed a plane without help?

Things that don't count:

- A computer does all or almost all of the work, e.g. Garmin Autoland
- The aircraft lands itself without intervention, e.g. Cornfield Bomber
- The person built the aircraft, e.g. the Wright Brothers

Comment: As has often been discussed, it is possible for a plane to land without any person or computer controlling it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornfield_Bomber

Comment: Not precisely duplicates, but this sort of thing has been discussed at length previously: [Has Air Traffic Control ever had to talk a first time pilot through a landing due to an emergency?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25260/has-air-traffic-control-ever-had-to-talk-a-first-time-pilot-through-a-landing-du), [Can a passenger realistically replace suddenly incapacitated pilots?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8986/can-a-passenger-realistically-replace-suddenly-incapacitated-pilots).

Comment: Do Orville and Wilbur Wright count?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I edited the question to cover the scenario of the plane landing itself.

Comment: @RobMcDonald I edited it to exclude builders of planes.

Comment: Is this limited to soft landing or just any landing. Crash landing is hard landing hence is also landing.

Comment: @GregHewgill I'd say the first question you linked is an _exact_ duplicate.

Comment: @user3528438 any survivable landing counts. I edited the question.

Comment: @Jamiec it's not a duplicate because that question is asking about someone landing a plane with help from ATC, while this is about someone doing it with no help.

Comment: @RobMcDonald To be pedantic, Wilber and Orville Wright landed a glider with no flight training.  When they landed planes, they already had flight training from gliders.

Comment: An interesting alternative to the "pilot incapacitated" situation, but which I believe would qualify is: Someone spends many hours with advanced flight simulator software, studies manuals for the plane they want to fly, etc. and then goes ahead and "borrows" a plane for the first flight with no instructor or radio guidance - takeoff and landing successful.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I thought about that -- While I agree they had flight experience, did they have flight 'training'?  I would also posit that the question could be generalized to 'aircraft' instead of 'plane'  -- which would simply move the question to their first landing of a glider.  For that, they had experience with their kites and of course bicycles.  When do we stop including perhaps relevant experience?  Once we're talking aircraft, we shouldn't forget the Montgolfier brothers.

Comment: I just realized the title says aircraft -- while the text says 'plane'.  I'll take that to mean that gliders, balloons, autogyros, helicopters, etc. are all germane.  Of course the OP has ruled out all of these folks as the builders.

Comment: @RobMcDonald My inexpert opinion was that the Wrights intended their glider flights to be training for powered flight.  Kites have different controls.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly.

On [2023 July 15](https://apnews.com/article/plane-crash-medical-emergency-marthas-vineyard-75b2f178a97c33e4e8fb3c9ce00009a3), on final to Martha's Vineyard Airport, the pilot Randolph Bonnist became incapacitated.
His wife took control of the Piper Meridian and landed roughly on the grass next to a runway, damaging the airplane but
without personal injury (as the saying goes, a good landing is one you can walk away from).
It has not yet been reported if she had any training or ATC assistance.

That she missed the runway makes it plausible that she had neither pilot training nor ATC assistance.
Either of those would have advised a go-around,
had the airplane drifted off course while she was deciding to take the controls.
Any assistance from her husband must have been rudimentary.
In the brief time before landing, she may have chosen to land immediately as best as she could,
instead of wasting time figuring out how to hail ATC.

She had likely watched landings before as a passenger, but that doesn't count as training.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if a go-around would have been a good call. If she really had zero training it might be better to take the off-runway but relatively stabilized landing then go around, risk a departure stall, and possibly end up with a less stable approach.

Comment: Good point.  That suggests the question: has ATC ever advised an untrained pilot to ditch off-runway when a go-around was technically possible?

Comment: "*has ATC ever advised an untrained pilot to ditch off-runway*", this is also an interesting question about the legal framework for ATCO in such situations.

Comment: @mins does ATC have some kind of emergency authority to violate regulations, similar to how pilots do?

Comment: @Someone: Neither the crew nor ATC, nor us, are allowed to violate regulations. But anyone can ignore regulations to save their life. This is still a violation you are liable for, but there is no penalty, if used with good faith, because this is like "force majeure" for contracts. However civil compensation will be due by the author in case damages or injury to others, because the law was breached. ATC would have to prove the life of the passengers was at stake and there was no other possibility. Difficult.

Comment: @mins so there's no equivalent of FAR 91.3(b) for ATC?

Comment: @Someone: I'm not a legal guy, and I may be wrong, but to me FAR 91.3(b) doesn't add anything to the rights of the pilot, it only reaffirms a fundamental right (every human being has the inherent right to life) which is part of the Human rights ratified by many States.

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly. You don't legally need any sort of training to fly an ultralight. Statistically, there are enough stupid people that it's certain *many* people have made such a poor decision, and they haven't all died.

If you search "flying an ultralight with no training," you can even find many such videos. No doubt, many of them built their own, but it's unlikely they *all* did.

Comment: I'm sure people have flown certificated aircraft without training as well. But that's illegal so people are probably more circumspect about admitting it.

Comment: Your answer likely applies especially to ultralight *gliders*, e.g. hang gliders.